# specific mysql php query

Tags: php, mysql

some question. in mysql db i have some rows like

```
car->ford blue,
price -> 5000,
date -> 2014-08-04


car->ford blue,
price -> 5250,
date -> 2014-08-06


car->ford blue,
price -> 4320,
date -> 2014-08-05


car->seat white,
price -> 3000,
date -> 2014-08-04


car->seat white,
price -> 3400,
date -> 2014-08-05


car->seat white,
price -> 6480,
date -> 2014-08-06
```

...

now i have to find the newest and the entry before the newest  order by car. can enyone help me please?

think my brain was washed to hot :)

*edit*
oh sorry -.- i need the following output

```
car->ford blue,price -> 5250,date -> 2014-08-06 
car->ford blue,price -> 4320, date -> 2014-08-05 

car->seat white,price -> 6480,date -> 2014-08-06 
car->seat white,price -> 3400,date -> 2014-08-05 

...
```

thanks very much

greetings

Comment: oh sorry -.- i need the following output

    car->ford blue,price -> 5250,date -> 2014-08-06
    car->ford blue,price -> 4320, date -> 2014-08-05

    car->seat white,price -> 6480,date -> 2014-08-06
    car->seat white,price -> 3400,date -> 2014-08-05

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited according to OP's updated request**

If you want the most two recent for each car, assuming that you have an `id` column:

```
SELECT *
    FROM cars c1
    WHERE c1.id = (SELECT id FROM cars c2 WHERE c2.car=c1.car ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)
       OR c1.id = (SELECT id FROM cars c2 WHERE c2.car=c1.car ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1,1)
    ORDER BY car,date DESC
```

There's probably a much more elegant way of doing it, but I'm lazy today.

SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17cf4/5

Comment: on top i have edit my first post. sorry its not my day today -.-

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 2 most recents, you have to order results par date, then limit result to 2 rows :

```
SELECT *
FROM cars
ORDER BY date DESC, car
LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems as you are looking to find second max of cars

may be this can help you:

`SELECT car FROM (SELECT car FROM cars ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2) ORDER BY date LIMIT 1`

this will give you definitely second newest car.

Answer (score 0):

you should primary key  `id` which can be INT(11) and set it to auto increment.

so the get the last two cars, your use the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `Cars` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 2
```